# Multiple (Two) ng-repeats on DataTable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-datatables

Now I know this is a very common topic but I'm not getting any solutions from the SO questions that I saw till now. I'm currently working on a page that has a `DataTable` whose data is coming from the **controller** and by using `ng-repeat`. However, the case here is that I have to use two `ng-repeat`s on the table.

The JSON is as below:

```
{
  "mainData": [
    {
    "goal": "ValueOne",
    "array": [
      {
        "LowerKeyOne": "LowerValueOne",
        "LowerKeyTwo": "LowerValueOne",
        "LowerKeyThree": "LowerValueOne"
      },
      {
        "LowerKeyOne": "LowerValueTwo",
        "LowerKeyTwo": "LowerValueTwo",
        "LowerKeyThree": "LowerValueTwo"
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "goal": "ValueTwo",
    "array": [
      {
        "LowerKeyOne": "LowerValueThree",
        "LowerKeyTwo": "LowerValueThree",
        "LowerKeyThree": "LowerValueThree"
      },
      {
        "LowerKeyOne": "LowerValueFour",
        "LowerKeyTwo": "LowerValueFour",
        "LowerKeyThree": "LowerValueFour"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

The HTML is as below:

```
<div class="ibox-content table-responsive">
    <div ng-repeat="data in mainData">
        <div ng-repeat="cond in data.array">
            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-tr-th">
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Other Header</th>
                    <th>Another Header</th>
                    <th>Extra Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data.goal}}</td>
                    <td>{{cond.LowerKeyOne}}</td>
                    <td>{{cond.LowerKeyTwo}}</td>
                    <td>{{cond.LowerKeyThree}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've used many different options, like e.g -

- Adding `ng-repeat="(key, value) in JSONObject" ng-if="key=='mainData'"` in `<tbody>`
- Two `ng-repeat`s, one in `<tbody>` and one in `<tr>` after `<tbody>`
- Adding `<div>` tags before `<table>` and also tried adding before `<tbody>` *(before `<tbody>` as it was suggested in one of the SO answers on the same topic)*

The last option resulted me in the following **error** -

> Error: Expected expression in form of "*item* in *collection*[ track
>   by *id*]" but got "{0}"

- Also tried using `limitTo:1` filter, but no resulted no success.

Any helpful comment is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Second line in HTML should be:
<div ng-repeat="data in mainData track by data.goal">

Comment: @BharatGupta adding `track by data.goal` isn't helping. I'm getting the same error mentioned in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/uakzrjjn/)

```
<table ng-repeat="data in data.mainData | limitTo: 1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Other header</th>
      <th>Another header</th>
      <th>Extra header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="data in data.mainData track by @index">
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data.array">
      <td>{{data.goal}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyOne}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyTwo}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyThree}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Including the specific part of your needs for your comment and answer.*

Comment: I did this, but this code results in two tables. What I need is a single table showing all 4 elements.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I've tried placing `ng-repeat` in `<tbody>` before but its throwing me error - **Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**
I've the same code structure in another file and there its working all fine. Don't know what is going wrong here :/

Comment: @Trivedi Well if your data is different from the one you provided, I can't help you more... See [my working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/uakzrjjn/), you maybe missed something in the synthax...

Comment: no, that's the problem. The object that is there in your fiddle and the object that I'm using are the same. Exact. I'm not able to understand what's going wrong here.
Also, could you give me some idea on what should be done for the error ?

Comment: @Trivedi This error tells you that your object is **undefined**. That's why it can't found the property (`match`) you are looking for. I think you have an error in your synthax, and trying to display an **inexisting** object (`undefined`).

Comment: I'm stumped right now. The object is correct, the code also looks right. I'm out of options to try here!
Anyways, thanks for your help @Mistalis. And if you come across any other solution / option to try then do let me know.

Comment: @Trivedi Create a Fiddle of your code. Else I can't do more for you.

Comment: its just a matter of accepting whose answer. Would you make the couple of changes made in my answer so that I will accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Mistalis's answer is almost correct, but in my case I had to make a few changes to get the solution and hence have posted this answer.

The solution is -

```
<table ng-repeat="data in data.mainData | limitTo: 1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Other header</th>
      <th>Another header</th>
      <th>Extra header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="data in data.mainData track by @index">
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data.array">
      <td>{{data.goal}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyOne}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyTwo}}</td>
      <td>{{d.LowerKeyThree}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Not yet sure as to why had to write `ng-repeat="data in mainData"` twice.